# Multiple Rubies under apache in production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I want to run multiple rubies on our production server.  We have some ruby 1.9.3 rails 3.2 sites going live as well as keep older 1.8 sites.  I understand that Passenger 3.2 will be able to do this natively but isn't live yet.
So for now, is this the best way to do this?

http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apache passenger module can't do this. You could however run [passenger standalone](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html) for each app (with a different ruby version) and then proxy from apache to passenger standalone.

You could of course also proxy to unicorn, thin etc.

Comment: yeah thats what the link i have above says.  However, passenger 3.2 should support it natively but who knows when that will be out.

Answer (score 0):

What about using multiple VMs/Slices for your different versions of ruby and rails, that way you have more control of your enviroment and don't have to worry about your different rubies/rails causing headaches with each other.

**EDIT**

Another solution that I have heard of but haven't tried is setting multiple users and running each version of ruby/rails per a different user

Comment: what about setting up multiple users for each version of Ruby/Rails

Comment: interesting, so how would that work with apache and passenger?  Right now, it only allows one ruby and gemset per server.

Comment: Like I said i haven't tried before but maybe setup Apache like this http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DifferentUserIDsUsingReverseProxy then since passenger gets the ruby version based on your path variable just have you different users point to different rubies via your path variable

Comment: it seems like the consensus is reverse proxy